# Append data from html table instead of save as new file

Tags: javascript

I work on a project where the data from table will change on button click.
How can i append the data to file on a new line instead save to a file in this code:
[code](https://jsfiddle.net/gengns/j1jm2tjx/)

```
function download_csv(csv, filename) {
var csvFile;
var downloadLink;

csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});
downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = filename;
downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
downloadLink.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();}

function export_table_to_csv(html, filename) {
var csv = [];
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
        row.push(cols[j].innerText);
    csv.push(row.join(","));        
}
download_csv(csv.join("\n"), filename);}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
var html = document.querySelector("table").outerHTML;
export_table_to_csv(html, "table.csv");});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot append/modify files on the client side. You have to generate a new file with the new data instead.